# Express JS - jwt sign exp missing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Express JS + TypeScript

The code:

```
              var token = jwt.sign({ foo: "foo" }, config.secret, {
                expiresIn: 60
              });
               res.json({
                    type: true,
                    token: token
                });
```

The generated token `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmb28iOiJmb28iLCJpYXQiOjE0NjIzNzg5NTB9.jTQSGYaCwyNhhdAi-5OhoAsTRIUhcX7htZbsOmQYGg4`

parsed to:

```
HEADER:ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE

{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}
PAYLOAD:DATA

{
  "foo": "foo",
  "iat": 1462378950
}
VERIFY SIGNATURE
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),

secret

)
```

as u can see the exp field is missing from the PAYLOAD:DATA.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The file that is set by `typings install jsonwebtoken` cmd uses wrong (old?) api

replace this file with:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/retyped/jsonwebtoken-tsd-ambient/master/jsonwebtoken.d.ts

and change `expiresIn` to `expiresInMinutes`